# How do I retrieve values from a nested Oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, procedures

I have kind of a tricky Oracle problem. I am trying to select one set of data, we'll call items. For each item I want to call another procedure and return an Inventory Item. I have two operations I am not sure on how to perform.

1. How do I retrieve a value from the nested procedure?
2. How do I return those retrieved values in the form of SYS_REFCURSOR?

My attempt here was to put the results from spSelect_Inv_Search into a nested table called ITEMS_TABLE. This is not working.

Code below

```
PROCEDURE SPSELECT_ITEM (IO_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS   
  MY_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE ITEM_TYPE IS TABLE OF ITEMS.ITEM_NO%TYPE;
  ITEM_TABLE ITEM_TYPE := ITEM_TYPE();

  CURSOR ITEMS_CURSOR IS
      SELECT ITEM_NO 
      FROM ITEMS;

  V_COUNTER INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR ITEM_REC IN ITEM_CURSOR LOOP
    V_COUNTER := V_COUNTER + 1;
    ITEM_TABLE.EXTEND;
    ITEM_TABLE(V_COUNTER) := spSelect_Inv_Search(ITEM_REC.ITEM_NO, MY_CURSOR);
  END LOOP;
END SPSELECT_ITEMS;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is not working?  Are you getting an error?  Is the procedure doing something you don't expect or not doing something you do expect?  What does `spSelect_Inv_Search` return?  What do you want `IO_CURSOR` to reference when the procedure completes?

Comment: spselect_Inv_Search returns an SYS_REFCURSOR. I don't know how to retrieve anything from spSelect_Inv_Search. That is my first problem. IO_CURSOR should reference the nested table created from loop calling the spSelect_Inv_Search. That is my second problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to merge an unknown number of `SYS_REFCURSOR` result sets into one big one. If you know the structure of the cursor returned from `spSelect_Inv_Search` you can do this with an intermediate pipelined function.

```
create package p as
    type tmp_rec_type is record (owner all_objects.owner%type,
        object_type all_objects.object_type%type,
        objects number);
    type tmp_rec_table is table of tmp_rec_type;

    procedure proc1(p_owner in varchar2, p_cursor out sys_refcursor);
    function func2 return tmp_rec_table pipelined;
    procedure proc3(p_cursor out sys_refcursor);
end;
/
```

The types can be defined here, they don't have to be at SQL level as you won't ever need to reference them outside the package.

```
create package body p as
    procedure proc1(p_owner in varchar2, p_cursor out sys_refcursor) as
    begin
        open p_cursor for select owner, object_type, count(*)
            from all_objects
            where owner = p_owner
            group by owner, object_type;
    end;

    function func2 return tmp_rec_table pipelined as
        cursor c1 is select distinct owner
            from all_tables where owner in ('SYS','SYSTEM');
        tmp_cursor sys_refcursor;
        tmp_rec tmp_rec_type;
    begin
        for r1 in c1 loop
            proc1(r1.owner, tmp_cursor);
            loop
                fetch tmp_cursor into tmp_rec;
                exit when tmp_cursor%notfound;
                pipe row(tmp_rec);
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end;

    procedure proc3(p_cursor out sys_refcursor) as
    begin
        open p_cursor for select * from table(func2);
    end;
end p;
/
```

Then to execute, which you can do outside the package despite the types used for the intermediate stage, you can do this to test in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:

```
var rc refcursor;
exec p.proc3(:rc);
print rc;
```

For my database this gives:

```
OWNER                          OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECTS                
------------------------------ ------------------- ---------------------- 
SYSTEM                         VIEW                1                      
SYSTEM                         TABLE               5                      
SYS                            VIEW                1056                   
SYS                            CONSUMER GROUP      2                      
SYS                            PROCEDURE           11                     
SYS                            FUNCTION            56                     
SYS                            SEQUENCE            1                      
SYS                            OPERATOR            6                      
SYS                            EVALUATION CONTEXT  1                      
SYS                            TABLE               13                     
SYS                            WINDOW GROUP        1                      
SYS                            PACKAGE             162                    
SYS                            WINDOW              2                      
SYS                            TYPE                529                    
SYS                            JOB CLASS           1                      
SYS                            SCHEDULE            1
```

This is obviously very contrived as you'd do this as a single query, but I'm assuming your inner procedure needs to do something more complicated.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately I do not know the exact structure that is returned in spSelect_Inv_Search's SYS_REFCURSOR. I will have to find that out to complete testing.

Comment: Okay, after getting the Inv_Search structure figured out, this is working. However, it is very slow. Is there a way to perform this function quicker?

Comment: Is the function really adding much overhead, or is it just repeated calls to the inner procedure that are collectively slow? I've often been surprised how what I *think* is a reasonably quick call based on a single execution is actually slow when called repeatedly. (Now I usually stress-test such things by calling them a thousand times in a loop to get a more accurate picture of the real execution time).

Answer (score 0):

In to answer your question about how to call `spSelect_Inv_Search`, I'd need to know the signature of that subprogram.  You've described it as a procedure but you're trying to call it as a function.  Which is it?  What return value and/or OUT-mode parameters does it have?

To return an open REF CURSOR from the above procedure, first the nested table type needs to be declared at the schema level (using a `CREATE TYPE` statement) instead of in the PL/SQL code.  Then you can open the cursor like so, after populating the nested table.

```
OPEN io_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(item_table AS item_type));
```

(And by the way, I would change the name of the type from `ITEM_TYPE` to `ITEM_TABLE_TYPE`, myself.)

Comment: spSelect_Inv_Search has 18 inputs and one output of type SYS_REFCURSOR. It is a procedure, that is the only way I've seen to call it.